# Inserting the results of a for loop into an html file - BASH

Tags: bash, sed, html

I have a script that takes the results of a command and puts them into a html code.

Here's what I have so far...

```
#!/bin/bash

list_dir=`ls -t downloads/`

for i in $list_dir
do
#----  
#       echo "<a href=\"downloads/$i\">$i</a>"
#----attempt 1   
#    
  ` sed -n 'H;${x;s/placeholder .*\n/<a href="downloads/$i">$i</a>\
                       &/;p;}' index.html`
done
```

I'm trying to get the results of the for loop to replace the contents of the html file where it says "placeholder" (I would rather have it just insert the content below a certain point without having the placeholders). I'm not too certain how to go about this.

Comment: You seem to be making a new account for [each](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77203/39428) question.

Comment: [Don't use ls like this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and be careful about parsing HTML with regex ([or you may inadvertently awaken dread Cthulhu from his watery slumber beneath the ocean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454))

Answer (score 1):

Parameter substitutions can be used to replace text without any escaping issues:

```
output=$(ls -t downloads | while IFS= read -r f; do
    echo "<a href=\"downloads/$f\">$f</a>"
done)

html=$(<index.html)
html=${html/placeholder/$output}
echo "$html" > output.html
```

You could also use `awk -v` to pass the replacement text as a variable:

```
awk -v v="$output" '{sub("placeholder",v);print}' index.html > output.html
```

Or use Ruby to replace a multi-line pattern without requiring a placeholder:

```
echo "$output" | ruby -i -e 'print gets(nil).sub(/<a .*<\/a>\n/m, STDIN.read)' index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the entire contents of the file, rather than somehow inserting your output in the middle, then your attempt #1 may be closer to what you want than an approach based on `sed`, if you redirect the output of the entire loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

list_dir=`ls -t downloads/`

for i in $list_dir
do
    echo "<a href=\"downloads/$i\">$i</a>"
done > index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would do that, but there's html code that needs to be preserved so I have to insert the results in a specific place.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your `sed` line, e.g. with variable `$i` in single quotes never getting expanded.

Given the following index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- placeholder -->
</body>
</html>
```

try using a intermediary files for the `sed` in/output:

```
#!/bin/bash

list_dir=`ls -t downloads/`

cp index.html out.html

for i in $list_dir
do
   sed "s/<!-- placeholder -->/<a href='downloads\/$i'>$i<\/a>\n<!-- placeholde
r -->/" out.html > tmp.html
   mv tmp.html out.html
done
cat out.html
```

Of course you will run into problems when there are filenames with spaces in them, but that is another issue.